# Workflow stopped working after changing to MacBook Pro M1

Tags: applescript

I have a problem with a workflow that stopped working when I upgraded to a MacBook Pro M1.
This workflow was used as a Quick Action in Finder files. First I tried running directly from Automator, and to my surprise it works, then tried again as Quick Action and doesn't work. I have been searching the Internet for more than a month and trying with different approaches but can't make it work again from Quick Action.

I have extracted just the code with the problem for easier explanation. The intention is to get the size of a movie file. The following code works inside Automator but issues an error when run from a Quick Action: cannot find the file.

```applescript
    tell application "Finder"
        set existingMovies to (every file of theFolder) as alias list
    end tell
    
    repeat with movie in existingMovies
        --repeat with movie in input
        set theMovie to the (quoted form of POSIX path of movie) as string
        set movieSize to do shell script "/usr/bin/mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -raw -nullMarker 0 " & theMovie
    end repeat
```

Then I tried working with input parameter of the workflow (in this case a list of files since this workflow uses "Workflow receives current: movie files"). With this approach it works both from Automator and as Finder Action

```applescript
    repeat with movie in input
        set theMovie to the (quoted form of POSIX path of movie) as string
        set movieSize to do shell script "/usr/bin/mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -raw -nullMarker 0 " & theMovie
    end repeat
```

In all scenarios I am using the same folder.
It seems that the list of files specified by input is somehow different from the list of files I create from a specified folder (existingMovies).

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate your problem on my machine, so I can't say for sure what's going wrong. But here's a 'best practices' reworking of your script. See if it solves your problem.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- always use System Events, not the Finder, where possible
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with thisFolder in input
            set existingMovies to (every file of thisFolder)
            repeat with movie in existingMovies
                -- dereference properties with 'get' 
                set theMovie to the (quoted form of (get POSIX path of movie))
                set movieSize to do shell script "/usr/bin/mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -raw -nullMarker 0 " & theMovie
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Somehow the code was working in the old machine. Many thanks for the advice, it works now both in Automator and as Quick Action